How can I read a binary file in C
I'm trying to read a binary file that has a sequence of integers, a file that has 100 integers in sequence.
The beginning of the sequence is:
20 2 22 4 22 10 5 5 4 1 ...

Using the xxd -b bin_100.bin command
I got the following result:
binary
But I'm not able to store these numbers in integers, when I print the results they appear like this
335544320 
33554432
369098752
67108864

For now my code is like this, I don't know what could be wrong
(and I don't understand much about reading files in C)
int readBinary(char* file) {
    FILE *binary;
    int result;
    int addresses[100];
    size_t read_size;

    char local[100];

    snprintf(local, sizeof(local), "assets/%s", file);

    binary = fopen(local, "rb");

    if (binary == NULL)
        return 0;

    result = fread(&addresses[0], sizeof(int), 100, binary);

    for(int i = 0; i < result; i++) { 
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, addresses[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}


It's a little weird to use &addresses[0] in this case. You can just use addresses instead.

@Yuri, Tip: next time, use verbatim output.  Format "%d: %d\n" could not output "335544320 33554432 369098752 67108864".  Post the code's true output.

x86 is little-endian.  Your file is big-endian.
This looks like it might be homework, so I'll tell you what you need to know, but I won't do it for you.
htonl will convert from your host's endianness to big-endianness.  ntohl will convert from big-endianness to your host's endianness.  You need one of them.

Thank you, I didn't know about big-endian, it was interesting to find out about it.
I tried in some ways to use what you gave me but I couldn't, I don't know why. Instead, I did an unsigned char buffer[4] and then I converted it using int value = (int)buffer[3] | (int)buffer[2]<<8 | (int)buffer[1]<<16 | (int)buffer[0]<<24; and it works
